# How to apply the offset .top to the height of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On this blog I want to edit the height of the #content div and make it height: x.top px (of the article:last-child) so that the background which is repeating itself vertically.

http://manutdstream.tumblr.com/

I tried to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
x=$("article:last-child").offset();
$('#content').css('height' : 'x.top px');
```

});

I think the problem is in the .css() as when I ran it to alert the x.top it went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just setting the height, no need to bother with `css`.  Pixels is the default unit for the `height` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lastArticle = $("article:last-child");
  $('#content').height(lastArticle.offset().top);
});
```

Not to nit-pick, but I'd recommend against using variables named something like `x` even for simple things -- unless you **actually mean** `x` (for example, coordinate spaces).  Code is already hard to read, but good names can make it easier.

Comment: For some reason it says 1210px when I tried to alert it as I realized it wasn't going all the way down to the last article... Any ideas why?

Comment: Sounds like you want `$(window).load(function() {... })`, so it executes after your images load.  Having looked at your site though, I'd recommend not using JS, and going for a pure CSS approach.  It'll be less headache and a good learning experience.  What you're going for is often called ["the Holy Grail layout"](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm).

Comment: I see, the $(window).load worked! but it kinda takes a bit and gives it this strange feeling... 
I looked at the holy grail layout and it is kinda like that, except the fact that I will only have the ads to the left and no right sidebar. Do you have any idea of how I could approach it in CSS, because I can't think of anything...

Comment: Same site, check out [the 2-column version](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is being treated as a string, place it outside the quotes and add it to the string with a +:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $("article:last-child").offset();
    $('#content').css('height' : x.top + 'px');
  });
```

Comment: you should post more of your coding, instead of a link, if you want to get specific answers

Comment: Perhaps there may also be an issue with x not being declared yet, ie `var x = ....`

Comment: it could be, depends on the situation, but he might as well use it to be safe

Comment: Basically what I have is <div id="content"> 14 articles </div>. And for some reason the content div's height doesn't change along with the articles inside...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `.css()` is incorrect, should be

```
  $('#content').css('height', x.top + 'px');
```

Fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/5vnbLr91/